# Reduce golang plugin file size

Tags: go, plugins, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build my plugin using `--buildmode=plugin` flag. the size is about `12MB` and it's quite large.

I've tried `-ldflags "-s -w"` flag which actually works for binary build, But not the plugin.
And the `goupx` and `upx` both only working for binary build.

Is there any way to reduce go plugin file size?

Comment: depending on your use case you can use gccgo for dynamic linking, your user need to have the go runtime shared library installed.You can consider not using unnecessary libraries, I have seen an key-value store database written in go have size of 12MB.

Comment: @nilsocket, actually the server is watching a plugin directory for plugins written in go.

Comment: Since the program is already loaded by the time you attempt to load the plugin you may as well compress it and decompress it to RAM before loading it. It's weird that they didn't use a `Reader` interface to make this simpler.